# elasticsearch - get unique bucket count in multiple aggregations

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by

I am trying to get the total count of buckets where my aggregation total is greater than some amount say 1000. Below are the documents sample.

```
[
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3FtHR8lArSPNJl_rcp",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 650,
      "custid": "2",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3F5UfjlArSPNJl_rlu",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 200,
      "custid": "1",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "orders_stage",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AV3F5UfjlArSPNJl_rxm",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "total_amount": 1400,
      "custid": "1",
      "client_id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

So first of all, I am able to get the unique records those are greater than 1000 in buckets but the I am getting the buckets count as 2 instead of 1. I am using following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "client_id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "customers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "custid",
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount_spent": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_amount"
          }
        },
        "amount_spent_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "amountSpent": "amount_spent"
            },
            "script": "params.amountSpent >= 1000"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "uniques": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "custid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to get the count of buckets that I am able to fetch using above query.

Thanks